# C++ function converting question

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming, type-conversion

I attempted to use `boost::function<x>` wrapper to store and convert my functional objects and I want to know if there a compile-check for **"does a conversion from arbitrary type `T` to type `boost::function<x>` exists"**.

Here is a code example:

```
struct Functor {
   int operator()(int) {
      return 5;
   }
};

// Should not fire static assertion.
STATIC_ASSERT( (IS_CONVERTIBLE<Functor, 
                               boost::function<int (int)> >::value) );

// Should fire static assertion.
STATIC_ASSERT( (IS_CONVERTIBLE<Functor,
                               boost::function<int (std::string)> >::value) );
```

*Now - does a way to implement the `IS_CONVERTIBLE` check exist?*

---

I tried to utilize `boost::is_convertible` type trait check, but it yields `true` for any `Functor` type:

```
bool value1 = boost::is_convertible<Functor, 
                                    boost::function<int (int)> >::value;

bool value2 = boost::is_convertible<Functor,
                                    boost::function<int (std::string)> >::value;

// At this point both 'value1' and 'value2' equal TRUE.
```

I also had the following attempts:

```
// Here the results are also always TRUE.
bool value = boost::is_convertible<Functor, 
                                   boost::function1<int, int> >::value;

// This doesn't work, because unary functions are constructed via
// inheritance (the result is always FALSE).
bool value = boost::is_convertible<Functor, 
                                   std::unary_function<int, int>::value;
```

*I really want to be able to check the possibility of such a conversion in compile-time, so
if anybody knows how to implement this, I would appreciate that.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @James wrote, it seems you rather want to have something like `is_callable`. [These class templates](http://ideone.com/lSZqt) handle functions/function pointers and function object classes or references to them for up to 5 parameters. Use them at your own risk :)

Comment: Who-hoo-hoo, thanks. Adapted version of this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::is_convertible` yields true when you test whether *any* type is convertible to *any* `boost::function` type because `boost::function` has a converting constructor template that takes *any* type.

Because this converting constructor exists, I don't know that there's an easy way you could test whether a type is *actually* convertible to a `std::function`.